# No keyboard input to VM condoles via VNC connection to virt-manager (Debian Jessie/KDE)

Tags: keyboard, kvm, vnc, libvirt

I'm attempting to provision and manage VM hosts remotely via a VNC connection to a server hosting libvirt and its associated KVM/QEMU hypervisor mechanisms.

All keyboard and mouse functionality WORKS when consoling locally to the individual VMs.

Accessing the same VMs remotely via a VNC connection FAILS to provide keyboard input to e.g. login.  I have keyboard and mouse activity through the VNC connection to the virt-manager hosting machine; and the mouse works on the individual VMs.  For some perplexing reason, the keyboard does not register on the VMs over VNC.

Any help here?

Comment: As this is 3 years old now, I wonder if anyone has come up with a solution? I too am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I switched to TigerVNC from TightVNC.

Answer (score 0):

Update the tightvnc works for me.
https://bintray.com/tigervnc/stable/tigervnc/1.6.0

Comment: There is some truth in this answer. I was having the exact same problem with `vnc4server`, then I decided to switch to `tigervnc-standalone-server` and the problem was gone. Here some other threads stating the same: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2225320 , https://serverfault.com/questions/973538/how-to-set-keyboard-layout-with-a-vnc-client-to-kvm-libvirt

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a keyboard to the VM.

atleast that is what i needed to do to get the keyboard working.

Answer (score 0):

I was using VNC Viewer. Switching from this client to Tiger VNC Viewer fixed this issue. No changes were required in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `Display VNC` of the VM from `Spice Server` to `VNC Server` and then the problem is fixed. The version of my VMM is 4.0.0.